# Haskell map with multiple parameters and type problems

Tags: haskell, dictionary

I'm currently working on a board evaluator in haskell. I'm trying to use map with a function with multiple parameters; I've read other SO questions regarding this but keep getting type errors so perhaps I'm just misunderstanding the Haskell types (I'm a Python programmer). Either way, here's the code:

```
scorePiecesRow [] _ = 0
scorePiecesRow (x:xs) y
    | x == y            = 1 + (scorePiecesRow xs y)
    | x == '-'          = 0 + (scorePiecesRow xs y)
    | otherwise         = -1 + (scorePiecesRow xs y)

scorePieces [] _ = 0
scorePieces board y =  foldr (+) 0 (map (scorePiecesRow y) board)
```

`scorePiecesRow` works just fine when I pass it anything like `"wwwb--" 'w'` (which returns `3`), but as soon as I call `scorePieces` (e.g. `scorePieces ["www", "bb-"] 'w'` which should return `1`), I get a bunch of type errors:

> ```
> <interactive>:37:14:
>     Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
>     In the expression: "www"
>     In the first argument of `scorePieces', namely `["www", "bb-"]'
>     In the expression: scorePieces ["www", "bb-"] 'w'
>
> <interactive>:37:21:
>     Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
>     In the expression: "bb-"
>     In the first argument of `scorePieces', namely `["www", "bb-"]'
>     In the expression: scorePieces ["www", "bb-"] 'w'
>
> <interactive>:37:28:
>     Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' with actual type `Char'
>     In the second argument of `scorePieces', namely 'w'
>     In the expression: scorePieces ["www", "bb-"] 'w'
>     In an equation for `it': it = scorePieces ["www", "bb-"] 'w'
> ```

I'm a bit confused by the error messages. The first one tells me, for example, that it's expecting `Char`, but the first argument of `scorePiecesRow` takes `[Char]`.
If anyone could shed some light on this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Haskell will infer types for you, they're usually very valuable to write out as well to both document your code (in a machine checked fashion!) and check your assumptions. We can do the work of Haskell's type inference engine here to figure out what we know about these functions.

Since `scorePiecesRow` is added to a number in `1 + (scorePiecesRow xs y)` we know the result must be in the typeclass `Num` (where `(+)` is defined)

```
scorePiecesRow :: Num a => ... -> a
```

Furthermore, by looking at the pattern matching in the arguments we can easily see that the first argument must be a list.

```
scorePiecesRow :: Num a => [b] -> ... -> a
```

and since we compare the elements of the first argument with the second argument using `(==)` we know they must be the same type and in the typeclass `Eq` (where `(==)` is defined!).

```
scorePiecesRow :: (Num a, Eq b) => [b] -> b -> a
```

Finally, the elements of the first argument are compared with equality to `'-'`, so we know they actually must be `Char`. Since `String` is a synonym for `[Char]` we can impute that.

```
scorePiecesRow :: (Num a) => String -> Char -> a
```

We can do the same with `scorePieces` to learn that

```
scorePieces :: Num a => String -> String -> a
```

and this is where we see the problem. You're calling `scorePieces ["www", "bb-"] 'w'`, i.e. with a `[String]` and a `Char` while `scorePieces` expects a `String` and another `String`.

The error is telling you exactly this, but it's a little confusing since `String` and `[Char]` are the same and GHC tends to reduce types to their simplest form when reporting errors.

Comment: Ah... that makes a lot of sense! Thanks for taking the time to step through it so thoroughly- this pattern matching thing will get awhile to get used to :)

Answer (score 1):

Because `scorePiecesRow` takes as its arguments a `[Char]` and a `Char`, when, in your map function, you call `scorePiecesRow y`, Haskell decides that `y` must be of type `[Char]`, as it is given as the first argument to `scorePiecesRow`.

This is the source of the third error message, as Haskell is expecting a `[Char]`, but you give it a `Char`.

The first two are essentially the same thing, in that `scorePiecesRow y` expects a `Char`, and so, when you map this function over `board`, Haskell expects `board` to have type `[Char]`, and it thus fails when you give it a board of type `[[Char]]`.

Perhaps try the following:

```
scorePiecesRow _ [] = 0
scorePiecesRow y (x:xs)
    | x == y            = 1 + (scorePiecesRow y xs)
    | x == '-'          = 0 + (scorePiecesRow y xs)
    | otherwise         = -1 + (scorePiecesRow y xs)

scorePieces [] _ = 0
scorePieces board y = foldr (+) 0 (map (scorePiecesRow y) board)
```

or, if you want to keep your `scorePiecesRow` function the same,

```
scorePieces [] _ = 0
scorePieces board y = foldr (+) 0 (map (\row -> scorePiecesRow row y) board)
```